# Classifying the singularities of $f(z)=z^{-2}\cos\left(\frac{z\pi}{z+1}\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I would like to classify the singularities of the complex function

$$f(z)=z^{-2}\cos\left(\frac{z\pi}{z+1}\right).$$

Clearly $z=0$ is just a pole of order 2.

The only other singularity i can see is $z=-1$

In this case, the numerator of the cosine function is:

$$e^{\frac{iz\pi}{z+1}}+e^{\frac{-iz\pi}{z+1}}$$

Just like how $e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity at zero, the function above has a essential singularity at $z=-1$

Is this argument correct? I am not sure if the second exponential term could somehow cancel out the behaviour of the first, resulting in no singularity at $z=-1$.

A second argument that i can think to justify this is that as $z$ tends towards -1, the cosine function will oscillate and not have a defined limi. THis also jsutifies it being an essential singularity, correct?

Comment: Do you mean $z^{-2}$?

Comment: @user361424 yeah sorry

Answer (score 0):

Check Laurent series expansion about the point $z=-1$ it contains infinite terms with negative power of $(z+1)$ and hence essential singularity.